# Modifications of Published Files Not Flowing to Final Location

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I'm trying to transition from the old Web Deployment Project method to publishing our web site using the FileSystem Publish in Visual Studio 2017.

With the Web Deployment Project, we had some tasks to remove a few directories and rename some files, when we ran MSBuild via the command line.  In the pubxml file that I'm using for the ClickOnce Publish, I have this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PackageDir>$(IntermediateOutputPath)Package\PackageTmp</PackageDir>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="CustomAfterPublish" AfterTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(PackageDir)\testcenter" />
</Target>
```

This does delete the testcenter folder from the temporary location, but that folder is still ending up in the final folder.  It appears that this is running before the files are moved to the final output folder, so I'm not really sure why it is there...

Is there another target that this would need to run after or a way to get a new list of files to copy, after I make the changes?

Answer (score 0):

> Modifications of Published Files Not Flowing to Final Location

I could do that successfully with custom your target `CustomAfterPublish`, you should make sure you have specify the pubxml file in the command line, like:

```
msbuild "YourSolutionPath\SolutionName.sln" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=ProfileName.pubxml
```

In addition, you can change the MSBuild log to detailed to check if the custom target executes successfully(Under `Tools` –>`Options` –>`Projects and Solutions` –>`Build and Run`, change the MSBuild project build output verbosity to `Detailed` or `Diagnostic`).

Besides, if we do not want include a folder to be published, we could exclude the specific files or folders by the elements `ExcludeFilesFromDeployment` and `ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment` in the `PropertyGroup` element in the .pubxml or the .wpp.targets file, like:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
    $(PackageDir)\testcenter
  </ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
</PropertyGroup>
```

See [Web Deployment FAQ for Visual Studio and ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158(v=vs.110).aspx) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Neither of those suggestions work when I try them.  The folder is still there in both.  When I try the command line, it doesn't appear to be using my pubxml file.  I've tried running this from different locations, but it just uses the sln file.  There aren't any errors either.  It seems like that might not be a setting that msbuild knows about.

For the second method, I tried that in VS2017 where I know that it does load the pubxml file.  VS2017 underlines ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment as not being in the msbuild namespace.